# How do I enable virtualization?

Tags: windows, virtualization, processor, bios, amd-processor

I was checking updates for my **BIOS**. And have the latest one which in the **BIOS** cannot show the option to enable virtualization. What do I need to do now? Also, I checked that my PC supports 
virtualization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, virtualization support is a common feature in most of the processors in the market. However, kindly cross check whether your processor supports virtualization . In case of Windows, this can be done with help of 'systeminfo' command at terminal, which lists the status as Yes or No for 'Virtualization Enabled In Firmware'. In case of linux, this can be done with help of 'lscpu' command that lists 'Virtualization' which shall mention 'VT-x' in case of intel processor and 'AMD-V' in case of AMD processor.

In processors like **AMD (AMD-V)**, *there might not be an option to enable or disable virtualization in BIOS as it is supported by default.*

However, in case of intel processors, the Intel VT-x is disabled by default in which case you may need to enable via BIOS.